What does "smudge one's clock face" mean?
https://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/4873807-trump-harris-debate-reaction-podhoretz/ says:

Former President Reagan speechwriter, John Podhoretz, said former
President Trump caused problems for himself during the ABC News debate
Tuesday night.
“He cleaned his own clock, and when he didn’t clean his own clock, she
cleaned his clock, and when she didn’t, Muir and David cleaned his
clock,” Podhoretz, now working as an editor at Commentary Magazine,
said on X Tuesday night.
“In the end, his clock was cleaned,” he added. “He smudged her clock
face a little.”

What does "smudge one's clock face" mean?

To be clear: "clean one's clock" is an idiom. "Smudge one's clock face" is not. It's extending the metaphor.

To be British: to 'clean someone's clock' is a more or less exclusively American idiom.

Grammarist defines clean your clock:

When someone threatens to clean your clock, they’re warning that they’re about to beat or defeat you soundly.


It can relate to a physical fight, a sporting event or any competitive situation.

This paragraph

"In the end, his clock was cleaned,” he added. “He smudged her clock face a little.”

Edit
means Trump was beaten.  The speaker probably used smudged her clock face to mean he was incapable of anything other than land a few ineffective blows.

Etymonline suggests that "to clock someone," meaning hit them, probably comes from slang using "clock" to refer to a person's face. "Clean your clock" is probably an extension.

In Britain, to 'clock' someone is to see and/or recognise them, and to hit someone would be to 'clock them one'. Mainly Cockney/London.

You've missed the point here, it has nothing to do with "self-inflicted". The speaker is putting "cleaned his clock" in opposition to "smudged hers a little"; in other words, she beat him up, while all he was able to do was land a few ineffective blows.

Thanks, @Daniel Roseman.  I've incorporated that.

@DanielRoseman a comment which fixed a misinterpreted and erroneous answer. You should have posted an answer yourself. Maybe next time, I hope you will.

The context is the 2024 US Presidential debate between Kamala Harris and Donald Trump.
Don't assume that everything a native English speaker says is correct, even if they are an eloquent speaker. Reading the Hill article, I am not clear about Podhoretz's meaning from just the text presented.
I'm interpreting Podhoretz's metaphor as saying that Harris soundly defeated Trump, even if he landed a few blows. Keep in mind that Podhoretz is a political conservative and may be sympathetic to Trump; it's possible that other observers may disagree on the extent to which he scored verbal points.
In addition, some observers have pointed out that Harris answered evasively to some questions on policy issues she might be vulnerable on, like immigration. Most politicians would do this to some extent. Nevertheless, her relative evasiveness and whatever points Trump scored could be exploited by conservative media. This may be what Podhoretz meant.

I am totally clear. Trump defeated himself and when he didn't, Harris did, and when she didn't, Muir and David did. In the end he was defeated, and Harris was slightly affected to a small degree.

Note, this is a site focused on how the English language works. The OP posted about a turn of phrase that was unfamiliar to them. The debate itself, or the political position of the quoted source, aren't on-topic here. Downvoting because this answer doesn't really address the question clearly.
